# Delete linkerd kubernetes namespace in "terminating" status

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubectl, linkerd, kubernetes-namespace

This is the resource status:

```
kind: Namespace
api
Version: v1
metadata:
  name: linkerd
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/linkerd
  uid: e7337b2b-bddb-4344-a986-d450973bc8cf
  resourceVersion: '5540346'
  creationTimestamp: '2020-05-10T13:49:21Z'
  deletionTimestamp: '2020-06-03T20:16:30Z'
  labels:
    config.linkerd.io/admission-webhooks: disabled
    linkerd.io/is-control-plane: 'true'
spec:
  finalizers:
    - kubernetes
status:
  phase: Terminating
  conditions:
    - type: NamespaceDeletionDiscoveryFailure
      status: 'True'
      lastTransitionTime: '2020-06-03T20:16:44Z'
      reason: DiscoveryFailed
      message: >-
        Discovery failed for some groups, 1 failing: unable to retrieve the
        complete list of server APIs: tap.linkerd.io/v1alpha1: the server is
        currently unable to handle the request
    - type: NamespaceDeletionGroupVersionParsingFailure
      status: 'False'
      lastTransitionTime: '2020-06-03T20:16:38Z'
      reason: ParsedGroupVersions
      message: All legacy kube types successfully parsed
    - type: NamespaceDeletionContentFailure
      status: 'False'
      lastTransitionTime: '2020-06-03T20:16:38Z'
      reason: ContentDeleted
      message: 'All content successfully deleted, may be waiting on finalization'
    - type: NamespaceContentRemaining
      status: 'False'
      lastTransitionTime: '2020-06-03T20:16:57Z'
      reason: ContentRemoved
      message: All content successfully removed
    - type: NamespaceFinalizersRemaining
      status: 'False'
      lastTransitionTime: '2020-06-03T20:16:38Z'
      reason: ContentHasNoFinalizers
      message: All content-preserving finalizers finished
```

Apiservices:

```
$ kubectl get apiservice

NAME                                   SERVICE               AVAILABLE                 AGE
v1.                                    Local                 True                      28d
v1.admissionregistration.k8s.io        Local                 True                      28d
v1.apiextensions.k8s.io                Local                 True                      28d
v1.apps                                Local                 True                      28d
v1.authentication.k8s.io               Local                 True                      28d
v1.authorization.k8s.io                Local                 True                      28d
v1.autoscaling                         Local                 True                      28d
v1.batch                               Local                 True                      28d
v1.coordination.k8s.io                 Local                 True                      28d
v1.networking.k8s.io                   Local                 True                      28d
v1.rbac.authorization.k8s.io           Local                 True                      28d
v1.scheduling.k8s.io                   Local                 True                      28d
v1.storage.k8s.io                      Local                 True                      28d
v1alpha1.linkerd.io                    Local                 True                      18d
v1alpha1.snapshot.storage.k8s.io       Local                 True                      28d
v1alpha1.split.smi-spec.io             Local                 True                      18d
v1alpha1.tap.linkerd.io                linkerd/linkerd-tap   False (ServiceNotFound)   24d
v1alpha2.acme.cert-manager.io          Local                 True                      18d
v1alpha2.cert-manager.io               Local                 True                      18d
v1alpha2.linkerd.io                    Local                 True                      18d
v1beta1.admissionregistration.k8s.io   Local                 True                      28d
v1beta1.apiextensions.k8s.io           Local                 True                      28d
v1beta1.authentication.k8s.io          Local                 True                      28d
v1beta1.authorization.k8s.io           Local                 True                      28d
v1beta1.batch                          Local                 True                      28d
v1beta1.certificates.k8s.io            Local                 True                      28d
v1beta1.coordination.k8s.io            Local                 True                      28d
v1beta1.discovery.k8s.io               Local                 True                      18d
v1beta1.events.k8s.io                  Local                 True                      28d
v1beta1.extensions                     Local                 True                      28d
v1beta1.networking.k8s.io              Local                 True                      28d
v1beta1.node.k8s.io                    Local                 True                      28d
v1beta1.policy                         Local                 True                      28d
v1beta1.rbac.authorization.k8s.io      Local                 True                      28d
v1beta1.scheduling.k8s.io              Local                 True                      28d
v1beta1.storage.k8s.io                 Local                 True                      28d
v2.cilium.io                           Local                 True                      18d
v2beta1.autoscaling                    Local                 True                      28d
v2beta2.autoscaling                    Local                 True                      28d
```

I tried deleting the finalizer, did nothing.
Also tried to delete with `--grace-period=0 --force` still nothing. 
It does not display any resources under the namespace.

Anything other I can do to force the delete?

Comment: Could you run `kubectl get apiservice` and share the output by editing your question?

Comment: Hi, I have added the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you experience is caused by the apiservice `v1alpha1.tap.linkerd.io` which is not working (`ServiceNotFound`). It is hard to say what have caused it but I can see two ways out of it:

1. If you don't need that API than simply delete it: `kubectl delete apiservice v1alpha1.tap.linkerd.io`.
2. If you need it, you can try to delete pods related to it in order to restart them and see if that helps.

After that you should be able to delete the namespace you mentioned.

Please let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `linkerd uninstall | kubectl delete -f -` and it will delete the resources in the right order so this error doesn't occur.

Comment: Thanks for this. This also works even if you installed Linkerd via Helm. I had some things left over that weren't uninstalled apparently, this completely cleaned it up!